# Finger.ID не работает корректно Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Таскаем предмет frontMovingButton по экрану.

```
void Update()
{
    foreach (var th in Input.touches)
    {
        if (th.phase == TouchPhase.Began && (th.phase != TouchPhase.Moved))
        {
            if (joystickIsAlive == false)
            {
                fId = th.fingerId;
                startTouchPos = th.position;
                joystickIsAlive = true;
            }
        }
        if ((th.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) || (th.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) && th.fingerId == fId)
        {
            currentTouchPos = th.position;
            frontMovingButton.transform.position = new Vector3(currentTouchPos.x, currentTouchPos.y, positionZ - 0.01f);

        if ((th.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || th.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled) && th.fingerId == fId)
        {
            joystickIsAlive = false;
            fId = -1;
        }
```

Вроде из - за FingerID у нас не должно быть никаких проблем со случайными нажатиями, однако если нажать сначала одним, потом другим пальцем и поводить ими туда-сюда, то предмет будет скакать от одного к другому, как будто и нет никакого FingerId. 
Что может быть не так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Магия, не иначе.Посмотрев логи заметил, что переменная сохранённого значения индекса fId корректно работает и всегда улавливает первое нажатие.

Но Unity почему то использовал любое значение тачскрина, игнорируя условие что

```
(fId == th.fingerId) = false
```

Переписал условие в другом порядке, добавил скобочек, и всё корректно заработало. Хотя, вроде как должно было и раньше работать.

Было

```
if((th.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) || (th.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) && th.fingerId == fId)
```

Стало

```
if(th.fingerId == fId && ((th.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) || (th.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)))
```

Comment: Потому что в первом случае у вас срабатывает  раньше всех `(th.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)` , а в условии написано `первое условие || остальное`, а, значит, если одно из выражений правда - то и всё правда.......вот и получается `true || что-то еще`....... а при расстановке скобок у вас получается, что должно обязательно и слева и справа быть true....

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял, вы хотите перетаскивать предмет с помощью касания. Тогда нет смысла перебирать все касания в данный момент. Используйте вместо `foreach (var th in Input.touches)` следующий код: `Input.GetTouch(index)`. Вместо *index* стоит указать ID пальца. В вашем случае это будет `Input.GetTouch(0)`. Не забудьте еще проверить условие, что `Input.touchCount > 0`. Еще, чтобы каждый кадр не обновлять ссылку на *touch*, нужно вынести ее за метод *Update*, а в самом методе проверять, присвоено ли ссылке какое-либо значение. 
Пример:

```
Touch myTouch = null;
 void Update()
 {
    if (myTouch == null)
        {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
                myTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        }
    else
        {
            if ((myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) && (myTouch.phase != TouchPhase.Moved))
            {
                if (joystickIsAlive == false)
                {
                    startTouchPos = myTouch.position;
                    joystickIsAlive = true;
                }
            }
            if ((myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) || (myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary))
            {
                currentTouchPos = myTouch.position;
                frontMovingButton.transform.position = new Vector3(currentTouchPos.x, currentTouchPos.y, positionZ - 0.01f);

            if ((myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended || myTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled))
            {
                joystickIsAlive = false;
                myTouch = null;
            }
    }
```